# Folder structure of MEAN Stack app

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am just starting on MEAN stack and coming from grails background, I am accustomed to "Convention over configuration" approach in frameworks.
For example, in grails we have folders for domains, controllers and views and you can not put for example controllers in views directory.

There seems to be no such rule in MEAN stack apps. Over various tutorials I went through I saw many different types of folder structures. The most common pattern was including a public and a server directory.

However according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32152407/1291122) SO answer

> Now the separation is at the module level

So basically to me it tells that there is no "Server" directory any more.

Also if you create a new app now using

```
npm init myapp
```

It won't create either a server or a public directory.

Now this is looking too confusing to me. So what is the recommended directory structure to follow while creating MEAN stack apps.

Also are there any resources available demonstrating the modern directory structure with "separation at module level"?

Answer (score 1):

There's no rules in MEAN apps, there's only examples you can work from. Node.js is complete anarchy compare to Grails, Rails and other frameworks driven by convention, but that's because no two MEAN apps are ever really the same.

One might be a real-time [Socket.io](http://socket.io) application, another an API, a third a component that only interfaces with a database and Redis. Each of these have different concerns and priorities.

Have a look at various MEAN/Node.js projects and draw your own conclusions for how best to organize things. If that means using Grails as an example, that's perfectly fine.